# Change bibliographystyle in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown, bibliography

I want to change the `bibliographystyle` in R Markdown but nothing I found could help.

I do not want any "and"s in the bibliography (before the last author).
My preferred option was if I could use `alphadin` (bst-file [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive//bibliography/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505)) but I could not get it to work.

Here is my YAML so far:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document
bibliography: literatur.bib
biblio-style: alphadin.bst
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{graphicx} 
  - \usepackage{float}       
  - \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{natbib}  
---
```

The bst-file is in the same directory as the R Markdown file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to set the bibliography style to use a bst file, you need to force R Markdown to use `natbib` or `biblatex` as the citation manager. By default, it will use pandoc to build the citation. [This article](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_packages_for_citations) explains the behaviour more.

Secondly, once you have that working, you need to change the citation style of the file. By default, natbib will use author-year citations, but the bst file you provided does not work with these. So I have change the citation styles to numbers.

Below is a minimal example. It will create a bibliography file `test.bib` but you need to make sure the alphadin.bst file is in the same directory.

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
     citation_package: natbib
bibliography: test.bib
biblio-style: alphadin
header-includes:
  - \setcitestyle{numbers}
---

[@R-rmarkdown]

```{r}
knitr::write_bib(x = "rmarkdown", file = "test.bib")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked exactly like you said, I only had to write just "test" instead of "test.bib".

Comment: Done! Sorry, I didn't know the "accepted"-function ;)

Comment: @MichaelHarper I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046041/how-to-change-bibliography-style-in-rmarkdown) if you fancy having a look:

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to set the citation style of natbib: `natbiboptions: round` in YAML. The combination of `citation_package: natbib` and `natbiboptions: round` is equivalent to `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`. Note that `natbiboptions: round` comes outside of the `output` key.

(In the following example, I used `biblio-style: apalike` but the example should work with any `biblio-style`.)

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
     citation_package: natbib
bibliography: test.bib
biblio-style: apalike
natbiboptions: round
---

[@R-rmarkdown]

```{r}
knitr::write_bib(x = "rmarkdown", file = "test.bib")
```
````